# Format json with nested objects for json2csv

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, recursion

Working with nodejs, I'm trying to format my json in such a way it can be used to download as csv using json2csv.

Example of question in json is answer["4"]["text"].
Example of answer in json is answer["4"]["answer"]. But not all questions have answers.

What I'm trying to get at the end is:

```
arrayQuestions = ["Welkom", "Het spijt ons dit te horen", "Wat is je email adres", "Hoe was je ervaring", "Click on next to continue", "Dankjewel"]; 
arrayAnswers = [ { 
                  answer1: "", 
                  answer2: "", 
                  answer3: "email@email.com", 
                  answer4: "4", 
                  answer5: "", 
                  answer6: "" }, 
                { answer1: "", 
                  answer2: "", 
                  answer3: "email2@email.com", 
                  answer4: "5", 
                  answer5: "", 
                  answer6: "" }];
```

So far I managed to loop through the json and its many nested objects and it returns all objects with the questions and answers. However, it does not take into account different entries, which I'm really struggling with to get right.

Hope anyone can help :)

```js
    var json = {
      "content": [{
          "updated_at": "2018-03-01 06:38:16",
          "answers": {
            "2": {
              "name": "clickTo",
              "text": "Welkom",
              "type": "control_text"
            },
            "3": {
              "name": "hetSpijt3",
              "text": "Het spijt ons dit te horen. ",
              "type": "control_textarea"
            },
            "4": {
              "name": "watIs",
              "text": "Wat is je email adres?",
              "type": "control_email",
              "answer": "email@email.com"
            },
            "7": {
              "name": "hoeWas",
              "text": "Hoe was je ervaring",
              "type": "control_rating",
              "answer": "4"
            },
            "8": {
              "name": "clickTo8",
              "text": "Click on next to continue",
              "type": "control_text"
            },
            "10": {
              "name": "dankjewel10",
              "text": "Dankjewel. ",
              "type": "control_textarea"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "updated_at": "2018-03-07 14:15:45",
          "answers": {
            "2": {
              "name": "clickTo",
              "text": "Welkom",
              "type": "control_text"
            },
            "3": {
              "name": "hetSpijt3",
              "text": "Het spijt ons dit te horen. ",
              "type": "control_textarea"
            },
            "4": {
              "name": "watIs",
              "text": "Wat is je email adres?",
              "type": "control_email",
              "answer": "email2@email.com"
            },
            "7": {
              "name": "hoeWas",
              "text": "Hoe was je ervaring?",
              "type": "control_rating",
              "answer": "5"
            },
            "8": {
              "name": "clickTo8",
              "text": "Click on next to continue",
              "type": "control_text"
            },
            "10": {
              "name": "dankjewel10",
              "text": "Dankjewel. ",
              "type": "control_textarea"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    };


    var answersArray = [];

    iterObj(json);

    console.log(answersArray);

    function iterObj(obj) {

      for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj[key].hasOwnProperty("text")) {
          answersArray.push(obj[key]);
        }
        if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
          iterObj(obj[key]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I'd like help with formatting my json so that 1. get an array of the questions, and 2. an array with each entry as an object containing the answers.

Comment: Are you are trying to map `text` property as questions and `name` property as answers ,corresponding to the JSON you have posted?

Comment: @Plaksel please state the expected output of your JSON, for clarification.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, this is expected output:                      

arrayQuestions = ["Welkom", "Het spijt ons dit te horen", "Wat is je email adres", "Hoe was je ervaring", "Click on next to continue", "Dankjewel"];

arrayAnswers = [ {
 answer1: "",
 answer2: "",
 answer3: "email@email.com",
 answer4: "4",
 answer5: "",
 answer6: ""
 },
 {
 answer1: "",
 answer2: "",
 answer3: "email2@email.com",
 answer4: "5",
 answer5: "",
 answer6: ""
 }];

Comment: I've updated my question above with expected outcome